# Pandas groupby and indicate whether a column has a certain value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

there are many similar questions out there but none that exactly address my problem.

I have a pandas data frame of users and locations. Users can have multiple locations. I want to transform the data so that I have a single location in the column per user. To do this, I would like to check whether a user has "New York" as a location otherwise put "Other".

So, user1 values:

```
 user1 : New York

  user1 : Boston
```

the output is:

```
 user 1: New York

 user 1: New York
```

Then user2 values:

```
 user2: Boston

 user2: San Fran
```

the output is:

```
user2: Other

user2: Other
```

I have tried this:

```
group_by_user = sample['office_type'].groupby(sample['user']) 
sample.loc[:,'office_type2'] = ['New York' if ele == 'New York' else 'Other' for ele in sample['office_type']]
```

But this doesn't populate 'New York' in both rows, it populates:

```
 user1: New York

 user1: Other
```

I want it to populate

```
 user1: New York

 user1: New York
```

Comment: don't forget about formatting next time =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC Let us do the `transform` with `any` , it will `groupby` the user check whether it have any new york or not, if so , for all row with the user return True

```
s=sample['office_type'].eq('New York').groupby(sample['user']).transform('any')
sample.loc[:,'office_type']=s.map({True:'New York', False: 'Other'} )
```

Comment: perfect thank you!  this structure helps me greatly for future transforms too